# How can I use a 3rd party script in my angular2 service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use angular2, with **angular cli**. I have created an app with angular cli, with ng new my-app. Now I want to create a service in which I need to use a 3rd party script. I see that that script is already in node_modules.

How can I include/import/inject/use (whatever) that script in my service?

I see some examples telling about adding to global scripts. But if I need it just for the service and nowhere else, why would I put it in global scope?

**my.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
(HOW CAN I INCLUDE IN THIS SERVICE NODE_MODULES/SOME_OTHER_SCRIPT)??

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3rd party script in your services so firstly you should have type definitions of that script. types definition can search on `https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/` like highcharts if available you can install `npm install --save @types/highcharts` in your project. Otherwise need to write type definition file ie.

Step 1. Create demo.js file in assests/javascript folder.

```
export function test1(){
    console.log('Calling test 1 function');
}
```

Step 2. Create demo.d.ts file in assests/javascript folder.

```
export declare function test1();
```

Step 3. Use it in your component

```
import { test1 } from '../assets/javascript/demo'; 
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor() {
    console.log(test1());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below line for import, replace circular-json with your 3rd party name. Also install the typings for your 3rd party script so that you will get suggestions like all other imports. [This link has all high quality types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)

```
import * as CircularJSON from 'circular-json';
```

Comment: Thanks! DefinitelyTyped link is useful.

Comment: Glad it helped :)